# How WordPress Database wp_posts tag1,tag2,tag3

Tags: mysql, wordpress

BAD

```
SELECT p.ID, tr.object_id, tr.term_taxonomy_id
FROM wp_posts p, wp_term_relationships tr
WHERE p.ID = tr.object_id
```

I want to make it like this, One SELECT code.

```
[ID: 1, object_id: 1, term_taxonomy_id: 1,12,13,15],
[ID: 2, object_id: 2, term_taxonomy_id: 15,18,19,25],
[ID: 3, object_id: 3, term_taxonomy_id: 13],
[ID: 4, object_id: 4, term_taxonomy_id: 7,31],
```

consultation

http://www.dimuthu.org/blog/2008/12/20/wordpress-database-relationship-with-tags-catagories-and-posts/

Database Description

https://codex.wordpress.org/Database_Description

Comment: You might look at GROUP_CONCAT, but a simple PHP loop would be preferable

Comment: It's so Great thx!